# Custom Web Component and Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli, web-component

I've created a custom web component located in the file: `wc-notification.js` and I want to use it in my Angular project built with Angular CLI.
I've included the file in `src/index.html`,but I keep getting error:

```
The resource from “http://localhost:4200/wc-notification.js” was blocked 
due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: put the .js in the **assets** folder, else angular can find it -or import in the main.app.ts-

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to do it the following way:

1. In `angular.json` under `projects/[my-project-name]/architect/build/options/scripts` I put:

```
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js",
   "src/sunpietro-notification.js"
]
```

2. In `app.module.ts` I've imported `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`: `import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';` and added that schema to module definition:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
```

3. Started using my custom web component in any component template.